# How do i disable utf-8 escaping in rails to_json output \u2013

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, escaping, utf

Json is supposed to be able to be parsed with UTF characters included.
In particular I'm talking about `-`.  Or as it seems to be getting encoded: `\u2013`

This is for a json api output, and there's no need to be escaping these `&`'s that are in text fields.  I wonder, how do people usually handle this in Rails 3?

Answer (score 1):

`\u2013` is not a `&`, it's a `–` ([EN_DASH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm))

Comment: Changed question to reflect actually encoding.  Question still remains, How to poeple generally handle disalbing of escaping special characters in Json output for Rails?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `\u2013` with `-` in your string before writing it into JSON:

```
string = '\u2013'
string2 = string.gsub('\u2013', '-')
puts(string2) #Will output '-'
```

After, you can write `string2` into yout JSON file.